# Getting the maximum / minimum value of a shifting sequence

Tags: python, max, min

I'm looking for the most efficient way to compute the maximum / minimum value of a shifting sequence in Python.

By a shifting sequence I mean a data structure like the collections.deque. However the question isn't limited to a deque if this task can be done more efficiently with an object like heapq or a simple list.

To my knowledge, the fastest way to calculate the maximum of a sequence for a list or a deque is via the max() function, which still takes O(n). Heaps sort values automatically, however the addition and removal of new elements takes O(logn), which would have to be performed on every iteration in order for it to be a shifting sequence.

So is there any other way to calculate the maximum / minimum of a shifting sequence which would be more efficient?

Comment: You can try adopt solution to [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-window-maximum/) problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "shifting sequence"?  A `deque` has efficient push and pop operations. A `heapq` also has push and pop operations, the sorting would only have to be done on push.

Comment: @Anentropic I need a way to efficiently find the highest/lowest value of a sequence that has new elements being pushed and old elements being popped. Like in a deque, if you have a maxlen param, the last element will be removed upon pushing a new one. This is what I mean by shifting.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you're dealing with an incoming data stream, for which you want to find some basic statistics (min, max average, whatever...) over a window of the last `maxlen` samples. I don't know what the **most efficient** way is, but I think the following investigation might be interesting at least.

1. **heapq**: I'm not sure how you could accomplish this (simply) with a `heapq`, since you lose the order of insertion, and will not be able to pop the oldest element. You can get around this by re-creating your heap from the incoming list at every "step", but at that point you're probably better off just using `min` and `max` on the list.
2. **list**: A naive implementation would be the following. It has the best performance for very short values of `maxlen` (i.e. less than about 100), since `list` is optimized for sequential operations, such as `min` and `max`, and so, while a step has a complexity of O(`maxlen`), it's still pretty good.

```py
li = list()
for i in seq:
    li.append(i)
    if len(li) >= maxlen:
        li.pop(0)
    lo, hi = min(li), max(li)
```

3. **deque**: for a shifting sequence, a `deque` usually seems like the "right" solution, since it auto-pops old values, and is optimized for exactly that. Unfortunately, it is not optimized for sequential operations, like `min` and `max`, so we still have a complexity of O(`maxlen`), but we don't take the hit for `pop(0)`. It seems that for larger `maxlen` (i.e. above 100), a naive `deque` and a naive list implementation will be more or less equivalent.

```py
dq = deque(maxlen=maxlen) 
for i in seq:
    dq.append(i)
    lo, hi = min(dq), max(dq)
```

4. **monotonic stack**. If you have very a large `maxlen` and you're willing to trade time for memory usage, a [monotonic stack](https://medium.com/algorithms-and-leetcode/monotonic-queue-explained-with-leetcode-problems-7db7c530c1d6) might be an interesting choice. It lets you cache likely minima and maxima, so that you don't need to iterate over the whole sequence at every step. I'm not sure what the complexity is, but for very large `maxlen` (i.e. above 500), the time gains are significant (about 5x faster than `list` for `maxlen=500` and 10x faster for `maxlen=1000`). The following illustrates a possible implementation (with bonus implementation of a moving average, because moving averages are nice):

```py
from collections import deque

class Statque(deque):
    '''
    A queue tracking the following stats, which are accessible as 
    properties:
    * min : the current minimum
    * max : the current maximum
    * avg : the current average

    Can be used like a normal collections.deque (i.e. using `append`),
    requires a `maxlen`.
    '''
    class Maxique(deque):
        '''
        Maxique is an increasing monotonic queue. It will contain a queue 
        of the next maxima, in decreasing order.
        Appending a new value will pop all values that lesser.
        '''

        def append(self, __x):  # O(len(self))
            '''Appending a new value will pop all values that lesser.'''
            while len(self) and self[-1] < __x:
                self.pop()
            return super().append(__x)

    class Minique(deque):
        '''
        Maxique is a decreasing monotonic queue. It will contain a queue
        of the next minima, in increasing order.
        Appending a new value will pop all values that greater.
        '''

        def append(self, __x):  # O(len(self))
            while len(self) and self[-1] > __x:
                self.pop()
            return super().append(__x)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._minq = self.Minique()
        self._maxq = self.Maxique()
        self._avg_acc = 0

    @property
    def min(self):
        return self._minq[0]

    @property
    def max(self):
        return self._maxq[0]

    @property
    def avg(self):
        return self._avg_acc/len(self)

    def append(self, __x) -> None:
        self._minq.append(__x)
        self._maxq.append(__x)

        # if the queue is full, appending it pops the last element.
        # need to do this manually here
        if len(self) == self.maxlen:
            self.popleft()

        super().append(__x)
        self._avg_acc += __x

    def popleft(self):
        # before the old value departs, we need to check if the exiting value
        # was an extrema
        old_x = super().popleft()
        if old_x == self.min:
            self._minq.popleft()
        if old_x == self.max:
            self._maxq.popleft()
        self._avg_acc -= old_x
        return old_x

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({list(self)}, " + \
            f"min={self.min}, max={self.max}, avg={self.avg}, " +\
            f"maxlen={self.maxlen})"
```

#### TL;DR

what is best depends on the value of your `maxlen` parameter and how much memory you're willing to use.